# Change library file while building app with grunt and wiredep

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, momentjs, wiredep

I have angular application from yeoman-angular generator.

I do have that code in index.html:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
...
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and then in Gruntfile:

```
wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
        }
}
```

The problem is that i need not just moment/moment.js in my project, but min/moment-with-locales.js. Of course, it dosn't help to change it manually in index.html.

Maybe there is some way to override which library file should be used for building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appeared to be not in Grunt tasks, but in bower.json.
I had to add:

```
"overrides": {
  "moment": {
    "main": "min/moment-with-locales.js"
  }
},
```

And grunt added that to build, so problem was solved.